# Put if condition within find method for 0th element

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, if-statement

I have an object with keys

```
const People = {
    groupA : ['Amy','Beth'],
    groupB : ['Ben','Matt'],
    groupC : ['Jen','Eli'], 
};
```

Now I am declaring a varieable where I will pass the values dynamical. for example

```
const Person = Object.entries(People).find(([,values])=>values.includes('Amy'))[0]
console.log(Person) //output 'groupA'
```

But when In pass something thats not in the object, its throwing an undefined error. I was not able to understand where to put the if condition.

```
const Person1 = Object.entries(People).find(([,values])=>values.includes('Brad'))[0]
console.log(Person1) // output should be undefined
```

I tried putting if conditions but was not able to handle both scenerios.

Comment: Did you mean `Object.entries(People)` in the second example? You can use the [optional chaining operator (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to protect against undefined returns. `Object.entries(People).find(...)?.[0];`

Comment: `Object.entries(a)` rightly throws a reference error, as `a` was never declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a not found entry by the function `Array.prototype.find` this function returns `undefined` when no element satisfies the handler condition.

An alternative is using the OR (`||`) operator as follows, this approach will return an empty array when the function `find` returns `undefined`.

Within the following code snippet, you can see additional alternatives.

```js
const Person = (Object.entries(People).find(([,values])=>values.includes('Amy')) || [])[0]
```

```js
const People = {    groupA : ['Amy','Beth'],    groupB : ['Ben','Matt'],    groupC : ['Jen','Eli']};

//OR operator
let Person = (Object.entries(People).find(([,values])=>values.includes('Ele')) || [])[0];

console.log(Person);

//Optional chaining operator (?.)
Person = Object.entries(People).find(([,values])=>values.includes('Ele'))?.[0];

console.log(Person);

//Nullish coalescing operator
Person = (Object.entries(People).find(([,values])=>values.includes('Ele')) ?? [])[0];

console.log(Person);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Nullish Coalescing Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing), this way you can returns. Default value if it is undefined, you would put this in the return statement after the ‘=>’

Or after the entire Object.entries statement in the variable depending on what is actually returning undefined.